# PDE solution uniqueness, definition?!

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have this PDE:

$$3u_x+u_{xy}=0$$ which I solved and got

$$u = F(y)e^{-3x} + g(x)$$

and using the following conditions:
$$u(x,0) = e^{-3x}$$
$$u_y(x,0) = 0$$

From the first condition I could infer that:

$$u = e^{-3x}(1 + F(y)-F(0))$$

From the second condition I could infer that

$$f(0) = 0 $$

So from this I could figure out several $F(y)$ functions that return a solution for the PDE. Examples would be a constant or a cosine function. Does this imply non-uniqueness?

Does uniqueness simply mean two functions that are not the same (i.e. there exists a point in the domain where they map to a different point on the range) yet both obey the PDE?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the PDE alone is not enough to guarantee uniqueness.

In general, when someone says that a *solution $u$ is unique*, they mean that for any other solution $v$, $u=v$ (they are the same). What you described above is *nonuniqueness*.